# collapse field in Html

Tags: javascript, html

How to make fields in Html which may collapse if checkbox is chosen.
I am programming in Django.

regards,
Gintare

Answer (score 2):

Touche Spacedman...

I'd recommend jquery as well ( http://jquery.com/ ) as it's *very* easy to use.

Here's some code whipped up in a heartbeat.

```
$("#my_checkbox").change( function() { 
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#my_html").hide(); // hide element with id="my_html"
   } else {
      $("#my_html").show(); // show...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a javascript library, such as jQuery - then its easy to assign animation actions to events. Read the jQuery docs to learn, or cut and paste the solution that someone else will doubtless put here shortly...

Note this isn't a Django-specific problem, its javascript and html.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery code below uses an image of a '+' and then a header. e.g. + Top Ten

I used it to create an accordion.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#hideable div").hide();
    // add css to show +/- symbols and labels - no point showing them if they don't work!
    $("div#hideable h3 a img").css("display", "inline");
    $("div#hideable label").css("display", "inline");

    $("div#hideable h3 a").toggle(function () {
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
        imgName = $(this).find('img').attr("src").split("-", 1); //grab the image name so that we get the right one
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", imgName + "-minus.gif"); //change img, alt and label to match action
        $(this).find('img').attr("alt", "-");
        var sectionId = $(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").length - 1);
        if (sectionId == 0) {
            sectionId = 10;
        }
        labelName = "#lblSection" + sectionId;
        $(labelName).text("click '-' to collapse");
    }, function () {
        $($(this).attr("href")).hide();
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", imgName + "-plus.gif");
        $(this).find('img').attr("alt", "+");
        var sectionId = $(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").length - 1);
        if (sectionId == 0) {
            sectionId = 10;
        }
        labelName = "#lblSection" + sectionId;
        $(labelName).text("click '+' to expand");
    });
});
```